# Click paragraph header to hide and display the following paragraph. Attempting to call the same Javascript function for each section

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to hide paragraphs by clicking the header. My function successfully hides paragraph one, but the paragraph two button hides paragraph one aswell. I know I need to specify in my function which paragraph I am aiming for, but I was not sure how to do that. I appreciate any help, thank you.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
alert(elem.id);
  var x = document.getElementById("hideDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
} 
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">
    <b>Button One</b><br>
</button>

<div id="hideDIV">
    <p>
        This is a sample paragraph.
    </p>

</div>

<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">
    <b>Button Two</b><br> 
</button>

<div id="hideDIV">

    <p>
        This is a sample paragraph 2.
    </p> 

</div>
```

Comment: You should have unique `id` for your `div` and you are not passing parameter  in your `myFunction()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simple use unique id like that:

```js
function myFunction(elem) {

  var x = document.getElementById(elem);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction('hideDIV')">
    <b>Button One</b><br>
</button>

<div id="hideDIV">
    <p>
        This is a sample paragraph.
    </p>

</div>

<br>

<button onclick="myFunction('hideDIV2')">
    <b>Button Two</b><br> 
</button>

<div id="hideDIV2">

    <p>
        This is a sample paragraph 2.
    </p> 

</div>
```

remember using `function name(elem)` <- mean that you must indicate what `elem` is in  `onclick="myFunction(WHAT YOU NEED)"`

Comment: Looks like this does it! Thank you.

Comment: Done. Quickly, is there a simple way I can default the paragraphs to hide, before they are clicked?

Comment: in that case if user reload all will reset. you must use cookie or session(php)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the name of the button associated with paragraph like this

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function myFunction(name) {
  var x = document.getElementById(name);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
} 
</script>

<button name="first" onclick="myFunction(this.name)">
    <b>Button One</b><br>
</button>

<div id="first">
    <p>
        This is a sample paragraph.
    </p>

</div>

<br>

<button name="second" onclick="myFunction(this.name)">
    <b>Button Two</b><br> 
</button>

<div id="second">

    <p>
        This is a sample paragraph 2.
    </p> 

</div>
</body>

</html>
```